# How to use php code in html file?

Tags: php, function, templates, loading

I created 2 part in my project:
part1: php engine and part2: html template.

In part1 I have a variable:

```
$test1 = 'This is a var.';
$test2 = 'this is another var.';
```

and in part2: I have a content:

```
{echo $test1; echo $test2}
```

Now, I want to create a function that it can load template in part2 and display variable's value in part1?

Comment: Gonna need waaaay more detail than that… What have you tried and how does it fail?

Answer (score 6):

The most simple way:

*foo.php*

```
<?php

$test1 = 'This is a var.';
$test2 = 'this is another var.';

include 'foo.html';
```

*foo.html*

```
...
<?php echo $test1 ?>
<?php echo $test2 ?>
...
```

Comment: thank you, but i see: some php-forum-opensource use template file in a different way. I want to understand how it :D

Comment: @EurékaSyracuse There are many ways to implement a template engine, you could read their source.

Comment: their source very complex. can you example easier ?

Comment: @EurékaSyracuse Do a google search, there is a lot of examples, and then make a question with the part you could not understand :)